# What /?linksource= and /?_its= query parmeters are referring to on Google Analyticts page level report?

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters

I have /?linksource=  and  /?_its=  query parameters attached to some pages. I am trying to figure out how these parameters are triggered. To notice that traffic pages with these two parameters attached  have been sourced via direct, paid and organic means.

See examples of urls:

/?linksource

/?linksource=ucu&_its=JTdCJTIydmlkJTIyJTNBJTIyYzZmNGY5OGEtNDI2MC00OWE1LTg5ZmItYzJiMmNlOTI3NDdlJTIyJTJDJTIyc3RhdGUlMjIlM0ElMjJybHR+MTY1MTEzODkzMn5sYW5kfjJfODIwMzFfZGlyZWN0X2U5ODI0ZmMyOTc3MzU1MDdlMDExYjViMGQzZWQwZjhmJTIyJTJDJTIyc2l0ZUlkJTIyJTNBMTE0MDIlN0Q=

/?_its

/?_its=JTdCJTIydmlkJTIyJTNBJTIyYmY1MDk1NDktNThiNC00YmFhLWEyZTItMzZkMDJmZWFiNmJhJTIyJTJDJTIyc3RhdGUlMjIlM0ElMjJybHR+MTY0OTQzODc3NX5sYW5kfjJfODE5ODZfcHBjXzUwMGU2NGE1NjZjYmRiZjI3YjllYTAwYjNkOWZlNWI5JTIyJTJDJTIyc2l0ZUlkJTIyJTNBMTE0MDIlN0Q=

Someone can help me to figure it this?

Answer (score 0):

These query parameters for us are being appended to our pages by the Lookalike Audience feature/tool which I think applies a tracking query string parameter like the one you've posted in the question.

https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/164749007013531?id=401668390442328.

If this is still an issue for you then hopefully it will give you a pointer to pick it up with whoever setup the lookalike audience account as this can often be a 3rd party agency or another team.